# How to compute a variable from an existing variable in SPSS

Tags: spss

I would create a variable in `SPSS` and add it in the existing dataset. Particularly this variable should be: `x-y` if `x>y` and `0` if `x<=y` (`x` and `y` are variables in the dataset). How can I do?

I'm interested to learn this both writing the syntax of the script as using the guided tool "compute variable".

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  The simplest is
compute z = max(x-y, 0).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one liner:

```
compute z = (x-y)*(x>y).
```